# $E_{n,k}= \bigcup_{m\ge n} \Big\{x : |f_m(x)-f(x)|>\frac{1}{k}\Big\}$.Show that $\lim_{n\to \infty}m(E_{n,k})=0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Let m be the Lebesgue measure on $[0, 1]$. Suppose that $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of
Borel measurable functions on $[0, 1]$ that converges almost everywhere to $f$.
For each $n, k$ let
$$E_{n,k}= \bigcup_{m\ge n} \Big\{x : |f_m(x)-f(x)|>\frac{1}{k}\Big\}$$
Show that $\lim_{n\to \infty}m(E_{n,k})=0$ for each $k$.

Is the following correct?
for each $k$
\begin{align}
E_k =\lim_{n\to \infty} E_{n,k}= \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{m\ge n}E_{n,k} =\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\bigcup_{m\ge n}\Big\{x : |f_m(x)-f(x)|>\frac{1}{k}\Big\}
\end{align}
where $E_k$ is decreasing in $k$ (???????), but since $f_n \to f$ a.e.

$$m(\bigcup_{k\ge 1}\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{m\ge n}E_{n,k})=0$$ 
$$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{m\ge n}E_{n,k}\subset \bigcup_{k\ge 1}\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{m\ge n}E_{n,k} \implies \lim_{n\to \infty}m(E_{n,k})=0$$

Comment: You are lacking an argument for why $m(E_k)=\lim_{n\to\infty} m(E_{n,k})$ (this isn't too bad to argue). Otherwise, it looks good. Also, the set you're calling $\lim_{n\to\infty} E_{n,k}$ is usually denoted $\limsup_{n\to\infty} E_{n,k}$ or, in probability, the event that $E_{n,k}$ happens infinitely often in $n$.